# How to get virtual joystick direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a problem. I am making a game that can shoot some kind of spider man rope , in standalone version i'm using mouse to point the direction, something like this:

```
// Get Direction
public void setTarget(Vector2 targetPos)
    {
        Vector2 dir = targetPos - origin.position;
        dir = dir.normalized;
        velocity = dir * speed;
        transform.position = origin.position + dir;
        pull = false;
        updateLine = true;
    }
```

```
// Set Direction On Pc Version
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
            Vector2 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            rope.setTarget(worldPos);    // another script will get this value
}
```

And Heres the problem :

```
// Set Direction On Mobile (The Problem)
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);

            rope.setTarget(direction);
        }
```

and it's working fine, but now i want to make the mobile version using virtual joystick that i downloaded from the assets store, i want to get the virtual joystick angle so that the rope can shoot to that angle direciton. Please help me , sorry for my bad english, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's one of two things:

You are using your "direction" as target and it looks like rope.transform.position + direction is your target position.

```
rope.setTarget(rope.transform.position + direction);
```

You are not considering camera angle. You should rotate your distance by Camera rotation y

```
rope.setTarget(rope.transform.position + Quaternion.AngleAxis( Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up ) * direction);
```